# How to downgrande a gem in the gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have this in my Gemfile.lock

```
 sequel (5.15.0)
```

I want to downgrade the gem version to the 4.39.0 so I go in my Gemfile and add a version next to the gem declaration:

```
gem 'sequel', '4.39.0'
```

and run `bundle exec bundle install`

But it gives me:

```
You have requested:
  sequel = 4.39.0

The bundle currently has sequel locked at 5.15.0.
Try running `bundle update sequel`

If you are updating multiple gems in your Gemfile at once,
try passing them all to `bundle update`
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems
```

.
So I try to run `bundle exec bundle update sequel` but it returns me the same message. 
How can I downgrade the gem?

Comment: While counter-intuitive, the answer by Holger is correct. Running `bundle update <gem>` will upgrade _or_ downgrade that gem to the version specified in your Gemfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to just call

```
bundle update sequel
```

without the `bundle exec` in front.

The issue you experienced is caused by `bundle exec` evaluating your current `Gemfile` for executing the latter command first. Here, it finds the difference between the specified gems in the `Gemfile` and your current `Gemfile.lock` and bails out.

In general, no bundle calls need to ever be prefixed with a `bundle exec`.

Answer (score 1):

First try to update the dependent gems. It could be that there are some broken dependencies to other gems if you are downgrading.

Best practice:

```
bundle update sequel dependent_gemnames...
```

If you do not find out the dependent gems you can also try to update all your gems. But attention! This can cause unwanted side effects.

```
bundle update
```

And the last and ugliest option is to remove your Gemfile.lock and run

```
bundle install
```

This will rebuild your full Gem Stack and should be able to create a working Gemfile.lock